# Problems with drop down list disabling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, textarea

I have two drop-down select lists in my form as well as a textarea box.

The problem I am having is that, one a user creates a record, the record is then updated by another group but what I want to do, is prevent the other group from updating both select lists as well as the textarea box. I have disabled these items but when the user attempts to submit the form again, it looks like these items are not being posted and looks like the values are NULL.

I am using jQuery:

```
   $('#DROP-DOWN1').attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass('itemDisabled');
   $('#DROP-DOWN1').attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass('itemDisabled');
   $('#TEXT-AREA').attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass('itemDisabled');
```

How I can prevent the user from modifying these items above but at the same time having the values posted?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `disabled` try `readonly`.

Comment: tried that but unfortunately you can still change the values, unless I have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Nice problem!

Can you hide them instead of disabling? Set visiblity to false

Comment: unfortunately not as the next group needs to view the values.

Comment: The next option would be to display a gray / transparent div on top of this form (which takes the same width and height) and write a onclick function for this where you call event.stopPropagation so that click doesn't pass through. Show this div on form submit. How about this?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to copy the values to an hidden `input` field. That one will get posted!

Work forward with this in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/uHQkx/

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of how to do this for both a dropdown/select list as well as for a textarea? Thanks.